# Whats wrong with my function for finding the 3 solutions to my set of linear equations using cramers method?

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm just starting out learning python with basic javascript experience. I am trying to make a function to solve my set of linear equations using cramer's rule in my math class.

Don't mind the comments, but as you can see I managed to solve the equations in two different ways in the first two cells. But when I try to make my cramers function, I don't get the same answer. It seems that after the first loop, something breaks. I'm also new to stack overflow so, so sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

[image]

Comment: post the raw code instead of images

Comment: so glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice that `for i in range(0,2)` returns only `[0,1]` so 2 is not inclouded. also, in your usecase, the first number   `(0,` is unnecessary.

also, you forget to reset B1 every iteration as kremer's rule requires!!!! so by the second iteration, the det` of the replaced matrix is already 0!
I believe you meant to do something like:

```
for i in range(3):
    B1 = A.copy()           //this line will make sense for kremer's rule
    B1[:,i] = b
    solution.append(np.linalg.det(B1)/np.linalg.det(A))
print(solution)
```